# ssh paramiko can't read xlsx files

Tags: sftp, xlsx, paramiko

I use paramiko to ssh

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )    
ssh.connect(Hostname, username=Username, password=Password)    
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
files = ftp.listdir()
dir_oi = "directory_of_interest"
foi = ftp.listdir(dir_oi)
```

and can find a read a `csv` successfully with:

```
remote_file = ( dir_oi +"/" + foi[-1])
with ftp.open(remote_file) as f:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, sep = '\t', header = None)
```

the minute I change `remote_file` to an `xlsx`, with

```
with ftp.open(uw_remote_file) as f:
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
```

I get the error `SSHException: Server connection dropped:` or `Socket Closed`

of note, I can run this line without any error `existing_xlsx = ftp.open(uw_remote_file)`

Any suggestions how to overcome this?

logfile as requested:

```
DEB [20220519-09:22:45.998] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] listdir(b'blah')
DEB [20220519-09:22:48.009] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] open(b'blah/halb.csv', 'r')
DEB [20220519-09:22:48.241] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] open(b'blah/halb.csv', 'r') -> 35323935333939313533313032363062
DEB [20220519-09:22:49.084] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] close(35323935333939313533313032363062)
DEB [20220519-09:23:24.790] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] listdir(b'blah2')
DEB [20220519-09:24:01.590] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] open(b'blah2/halb2.xlsx', 'r')
DEB [20220519-09:24:01.975] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] open(b'blah2/halb2.xlsx', 'r') -> 37343338363564356234303033663337
DEB [20220519-09:24:23.510] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] open(b'blah2/halb2.xlsx', 'r')
DEB [20220519-09:24:23.727] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] open(b'blah2/halb2.xlsx', 'r') -> 64646361316532373233663463613036
DEB [20220519-09:24:24.108] thr=2   paramiko.transport: EOF in transport thread
DEB [20220519-09:24:24.108] thr=1   paramiko.transport.sftp: [chan 0] close(64646361316532373233663463613036)
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 852, in _read_response
    t, data = self._read_packet()
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp.py", line 201, in _read_packet
    x = self._read_all(4)
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp.py", line 188, in _read_all
    raise EOFError()
EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\AppData\Local\Temp\24\ipykernel_33560\4051829457.py", line 4, in <cell line: 2>
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1376, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1255, in inspect_excel_format
    buf = stream.read(PEEK_SIZE)
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\file.py", line 219, in read
    new_data = self._read(read_size)
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_file.py", line 185, in _read
    t, msg = self.sftp._request(
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 822, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "C:\Users\alexander.huhn.adm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 854, in _read_response
    raise SSHException("Server connection dropped: {}".format(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Server connection dropped:
```

I can download using

```
filepath = uw_remote_file
localpath = "test.xlsx"
ftp.get(filepath,localpath)
```

so will go down that route and delete after use

Comment: Complete Python stack trace please + Paramiko log file + Can you download that file? I.e., can you do e.g. `fl = io.BytesIO()` + `sftp.getfo(file_name, fl)`?

Comment: You didn't provide the information I've asked for. Not did you really answer my question about the download.

Answer (score -1):

From the log it looks like it were able to open both files. `pandas` is running into EOF error, So, which means excel file is completely empty.

Can you confirm if that is empty.

Comment: when downloaded, was able to open and see the relevant data